# state is not getting updated using react hooks?

Tags: jquery, html, redux, axios, react-hooks

I have created one custom hook for the Api call. Am trying to set one flag value to be false, whenever the api call is happening. Once i get the response, the flag should changed to false. I have dispatching the action inside the api call, but i couldn't able to update the state value.

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import fetch from "axios";

const useApiHook = (url, reducer) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { loading: false });

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(dispatch({ type: "fetching", loading: true }))
            .then(res => res.data)
            .then(data => dispatch({ type: "success", loading: false, data }))
            .catch(err => dispatch({ type: "fail", loading: false, err }));
    }, [url]);

    return state;
};
}
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    const { url, data, err } = action;
    const currentState = state[url];
    console.log("action", action);
    console.log("state", state.loading);
    switch (action.type) {
        case "fetching":
            return {
                ...state,
                [url]: { ...currentState, loading: action.loading }
            };
        case "success":
            return {
                ...state,
                [url]: { ...currentState, loading: action.loading, data }
            };
        case "fail":
            return {
                ...state,
                [url]: { ...currentState, loading: action.loading, err }
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
const Comp = () => {
    const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
    const sample = useApiHook(url, Reducer);
}
```

can any one help me out in updating the state?

Comment: I  don't see where you pass `url` property to the `dispatch` function? You have a logic in reducer to set state for some specific url, but in dispatch function there is only `type`, `loading` and `data|error` properties. You save the passing data to `undefined` in store.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you are dispatching your action :

```
dispatch({ type: "success", loading: false, data })
```

you are not sending a `url` property, so the `url` prop in your reducer is undefined

```
const { url, data, err } = action;
// url is undefined
```

Secondly, I think you dispatch the `fetching` action before calling `fetch`, otherwise you will not see the loading effect in your application

```
 dispatch({ type: "fetching", loading: true })
 fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(data => dispatch({ type: "success", loading: false, data }))
      .catch(err => dispatch({ type: "fail", loading: false, err }));
```

Comment: Am sending the url in the coustom hook i.e., useApiHook of the comp functional component. Secondly am dispatching the action in the fetch like below:

        fetch(url)
            .then(dispatch({ type: "fetching", loading: true }))
            .then(res => res.data)
            .then(data => dispatch({ type: "success", loading: false, data }))
            .catch(err => dispatch({ type: "fail", loading: false, err }));

Comment: you are sending the url in the custom hook, but you are not dispatching it into the actions whereas you are using it in your reducer... Secondly, `fetch(url) .then(dispatch({ type: "fetching", loading: true }))` will dispatch the loading action after the completion of the request, I suppose this is not what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include url parameter in dispatching action

```
const useApiHook = (url, reducer) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { loading: false });

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(dispatch({ type: "fetching", loading: true }))
            .then(res => res.data)
            .then(data => dispatch({ type: "success", loading: false, data, url }))
            .catch(err => dispatch({ type: "fail", loading: false, err, url }));
    }, [url]);

    return state;
};
```